# How can I enable paperclip into acts_as_commentable_with_threading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have set up paperclip and it's working fine with the models that I created by myself.
I tried to do the same thing with the model, which was created by the gem called **acts_as_commentable_with_threading**
However it never saves the file_name where the picture is stored.  But it saves comment as usual.
This is really weird that it just won't take paper clip file upload.

Why?

**models/comment.rb** (Of course, I've migrated required columns in Comment table)

```
attr_accessible :comment_icon

has_attached_file :comment_icon,
    :styles => {
    :thumb=> "100x100>",
    :small  => "400x400>" }
```

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'comment', :user => @user %>
```

**views/users/_comment.html.erb**

```
<%=form_for :users, url: url_for( :controller => :users, :action => :add_comment ) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :comment_icon %>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

UPDATE:

**users_controller.rb**

```
def add_comment
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    @user_who_commented = current_user
    @comment = Comment.build_from( @user, @user_who_commented.id, params[:users][:body] )
    @comment.save
    redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => @user.username
    flash[:notice] = "comment added!"
end




def delete_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    if current_user.id == @comment.user_id
        @comment.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Deleted!"
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Sorry, you can't delete this comment"
    end
    redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => params[:username]
end
```

**models/comment.rb (automatically created by acts_as_commentable_with_threading)**

This was the part of Comment model. Does this matter when it's adding comment in my User action????

```
  # Helper class method that allows you to build a comment
  # by passing a commentable object, a user_id, and comment text
  # example in readme
  def self.build_from(obj, user_id, comment)
    c = self.new
    c.commentable_id = obj.id
    c.commentable_type = obj.class.base_class.name
    c.body = comment
    c.user_id = user_id
    c
  end
```

Comment: Would you please add the code of `add_comment` action of `UsersController`?

Comment: Please add `@comment.save_attached_files` after `@comment.save` and tell me what happens.

Comment: @AhmadSherif I did. It just create new comment but without Attachment:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line before `@comment.save` in `add_comment` action:

```
@comment.comment_icon = params[:users][:comment_icon]
```